# Getting (0 redux.applymiddleware) is not a function error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm getting (0,redux.applymiddleware) error for my react-redux App

Here's my code for the store part :

```
    import {c[enter image description here][2]reateStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
    import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
    import imReducer from '../reducer';


    import {ENQUIRY_FOLDER_NAMES} from '../constants/constants';


    const logger = (store)=>(next)=>(action)=>{
    if(typeof action !== "function"){
    }
    return next(action);

    }

    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined" && localStorage.getItem('id_token') != ''){

    let initialState = {hasMoreFolders:true,isFetchingFolders:false,prodError:false,enqError:false,requesting:true,enquiries:[],authenticated:false,hasMoreItems:true,isFetching:false,updateMessage:'',myProducts:[],isFetchingMyProducts:false,hasMoreMyProducts:true,myWFOBProducts:[],user:[],prevPath:'',start:0,end:20,returnCC: "IN"};
    }else{
    let initialState = {hasMoreFolders:true,isFetchingFolders:false,prodError:false,enqError:false,requesting:true,enquiries:[],authenticated:false,hasMoreItems:true,isFetching:false,updateMessage:'',myProducts:[],isFetchingMyProducts:false,hasMoreMyProducts:true,myWFOBProducts:[],user:[],prevPath:'',start:0,end:20,returnCC: "IN"};
    }

   let initialState = {hasMoreFolders:true,isFetchingFolders:false,prodError:false,authenticated:false,enquiries:[],hasMoreItems:true,isFetching:false,updateMessage:'',myProducts:[],wfobpCount:false,isFetchingMyProducts:false,hasMoreMyProducts:true,myWFOBProducts:[],folders:ENQUIRY_FOLDER_NAMES,prodDetail:[],catData :{},isUploadingImage:false,imageData:{},imageUploaded:false,updatedItemId:false,itemUpdatedMyProduct:[],start:0,end:20,pageType:'All',enqType:'A',folderValue:1,buyleads:[],hasMoreBuyleads:true,isFetchingBuyleads:true,offerData:[],purchaseCreditResult:[],orderId:[],loc_count:[],listing_val:{},blstart:1,blend:10,lead_purchase:[],blPageType:0,offerDataExists:false,expired:false,suggested:[],requesting:true,enqError:false,returnCC: "IN",success:false,purchase:false,decodePackageBuyResp:'',blpopState:true,refresh:false,expiredShortlist:0,searchlist:[],searchstart:0,pbrData:{},objBl:{},searchData:{},searchend:13,tabValue:"",isFetchingSearch:false,isloadedSearch:false,hasMoreSearch:true,get_products:[],searchsuggested:[],get_recentsearches: [], get_recentrelatedmcats: [], premium_brands : [],products_loading : false,searches_loading: false, results_loading: false, country_ip:[] , country_iso:[], country_name:'IN', searcherror:false, getbrands:true, get_latestenqbls:'', updatebrands : false, updatecats : false, updateprods : false} 




    if(typeof window !== "undefined"){
       var stateData = window.stateData;
       initialState = Object.assign({}, initialState, stateData);
    }
    const imStore = createStore(
        imReducer,
        initialState,
        applyMiddleware(logger, thunk)
    );

    export default imStore;
```

Here are the packages that i'm using as dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
"babel-core": "^6.24.0",
"babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
"babel-register": "^6.24.1",
"bcrypt": "^1.0.2",
"body-parser": "^1.17.1",
"compression": "^1.7.1",
"constants": "0.0.2",
"cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
"cors": "^2.8.3",
"css-loader": "^0.23.1",
"debug": "^2.6.6",
"encoding": "^0.1.12",
"express": "^4.15.2",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
"file-loader": "^0.10.1",
"formidable": "^1.1.1",
"geoip-lite": "^1.2.1",
"http": "0.0.0",
"import-export": "^1.0.1",
"inherits": "^2.0.3",
"ipaddr.js": "^1.3.0",
"isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
"json-loader": "^0.5.7",
"loader-utils": "^1.1.0",
"mime": "^1.3.6",
"next": "^2.3.1",
"node-env-file": "^0.1.8",
"node-fetch": "^1.6.3",
"node-uuid": "^1.4.8",
"path": "^0.12.7",
"preact": "^8.2.6",
"preact-compat": "^3.17.0",
"qs": "^6.4.0",
"react": "^15.5.4",
"react-addons-update": "^15.5.2",
"react-dom": "^15.5.4",
"react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
"react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
"react-html-parser": "^1.0.3",
"react-redux": "^5.0.4",
"react-router": "^3.0.5",
"react-scripts": "^0.7.0",
"react-toolbox": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
"react-virtualized": "^9.7.5",
"redux": "^3.6.0",
"redux-infinite-scroll": "^1.0.9",
"redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
"register": "0.0.0",
"request": "^2.81.0",
"request-ip": "^2.0.2",
"serviceworker-webpack-plugin": "^0.2.1",
"style-loader": "^0.13.2",
"sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "^0.9.1",
"uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.6",
"url-loader": "^0.5.8",
"uuid": "^3.0.1",
"webpack": "^2.5.1",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.2",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.0"}
```

This code is randomly throwing the above mentioned error(0 redux.applymiddleware) 
The error is occurring intermittently, and when it is occuring, it prevents any further execution of code!

Can't include complete reducer file, hence added screenshots!

[Reducer File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4bDY.png)

[Reducer File contd....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cusI.png)

Comment: Can we see imReducer as well?

Comment: @devserkan added screenshots

Comment: No idea right now, sorry. Though looking for similar problems there could be some default/named import problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it was a server issue! Everything else was fine